# Tinymce Windowmanager.open() Parameters

Tags: tinymce

I use wordpress and currently writing a plugin for the tinymce-editor. I use the windowmanager.open() function to show a modal, but I dont know how to hide the ok button in this modal. The official documentation is very slim: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.windowmanager/#open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are creating the modal as per the documentation link you provide, if so, then the **buttons** parameter let you specify the buttons to add to the modal and the actions of said buttons, like this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
  url: 'file.htm',
  buttons: [{ 
      text: 'Accept',
      subtype: 'primary',
      onclick: 'submit'
    },
    {
      text: 'Custom',
      onclick: function(){
        //Add custom action here
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Close',
      onclick: 'close'
     }
  ],
  width: 320,
  height: 240
}, {
  custom_param: 1
});
```

passing an empty buttons parameter gives no buttons in the modal, the 'submit' and 'close' strings in onclick button's parameter make the buttons perform those actions, you can add custom logic by defining an anonymous function instead, you can also add custom logic to the 'submit' action by adding the **onsubmit** parameter, like this:

```
onsubmit: function() {
  //custom logic
}
```

Tinymce documentation is not much help, I've been researching something similar this past days, these links might be useful for you: 
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.plugin/
https://docs.contenido.org/display/CONDEVE/TinyMCE+4#TinyMCE4-Writingownplugins